# SSRS desirable or not?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm an intern at a pretty large company. I've been working on a lot of SQL and PLSQL projects with the occasional SSRS report. My question is, is SSRS something I could put on my resume? Is it something that companies look for and it could add a little something more to my resume? Also, is the code used for SSRS report expressions a certain type of code? I've really just been teaching myself as I go and was just wondering.  I apologize if this should be posted somewhere else. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not specific to a programming topic so it could get different answers. I think SSRS is something you can put in your resume since even if the company you are applying is not using Microsoft's stack for reporting, the arquitecture is similar to other engines. So if you understand basic concepts to build reports in SSRS you can apply that to learn/build reports in other platforms, something that could attract the company attention. About expressions every platform has different expressions, they are similar too in some cases.

Comment: For me it depends on the field you will pursue. If you will pursue being a Business Intelligence analyst then SSRS would be very relevant to your resume. As far as i know, SSRS is just next to Tableau from the top lists of BI Tools so for sure a lot of companies will be requiring this if they are looking for a BI analyst.

Comment: Companies like it because it comes free with their SQL Server licence.  Why pay for extra reporting tools when you already have one that works seamlessly with your SQL Server install?

Comment: What everyone else said.  And yes, the expressions used I believe follow the VB Script/VB.Net syntax.  You can also use VB.Net code in your reports too. I use it code elements for UTC Time/Date conversions for example.  Can fire up Visual Studio, write a function and just copy past into my SSRS report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not the correct site for resume advice.